# How to use jQuery variable in SQL statement?

Tags: php, jquery, sql, variables

myscript.js

```
$(".tablestyleorchideeaanbod").on("click", function() {
     var value = $(this).find('tr:first td:first').html();
     lastClickedValue = value;
     console.log( value );
     var test = lastClickedValue
});
```

So when got clicked on my table with class tablestyleorchideeaanbod, var test will get a value. Let's say for example: hi;

So, var test = hi

Now I need to use this variable in my homepage, index.php.
In index.php I want to use the variable; var test, to use in a MYSQL Query.

For example:

```
SELECT * FROM thisismytable WHERE rowname = var test
```

How to achieve this?

Comment: You need to use [AJAX](http://jayblanchard.net/basics_of_jquery_ajax.html).

Comment: PHP runs on the server. Javascript runs in the client's browser. They cannot communicate directly, you need to use AJAX or post back the data in a basic form.

Comment: you say you need to use their selection on the homepage, is this table on the homepage?  It could be as simple as bringing them to `index.php?test=value` with a link

Comment: It has to be done without pagerefresh, can someone explain me how to do this with AJAX?

Comment: Click the link in my comment above - it explains *everything*.

Comment: There are tons of answers and tutorials about ajax. Find one, try one .. Then ask if you need more help.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".tablestyleorchideeaanbod").on("click", function() {
     var value = $(this).find('tr:first td:first').html();
     lastClickedValue = value;
     console.log( value );
     var test = lastClickedValue
});
```

Then you most use ajax to send the data to de server

```
   $(".tablestyleorchideeaanbod").on("click", function() {
      var value = $(this).find('tr:first td:first').html();
      lastClickedValue = value;
      console.log( value );
      var test = lastClickedValue;
      $.ajax({
            url: 'data.php',
            type: "POST",
            /*contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",*/
            data: {val : test },
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);

            }
        });
});
```

php script data.php

```
<?php
$val = $_POST['val'];
// do whatever you want here .....
//insert sql or select
?>
```

Comment: Hi can't get it to work so far, can u may demonstrate in demo or jsfiddle?
I'd like to show my code but this can't be done in a comment

Comment: this is the link for jsfiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/masterfermin02/bwk6gaLo/8/). @KevinAmmerlaan if you click on any td of the table you will see the data on a div call result